# Adding custom CSS and JS to Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shopify

I am working on getting vertical tabs for a page on Shopify, using the 'Atlantic' theme. 
As this theme does not have vertical tabs by default, I have used the external JS and CSS "jquery-jvert-tabs".

My question is, if I upload the JS and CSS files as assets, how do I link them to the page on which I want to use these and how to make use of these on the page after that, if I have certain style elements available there too?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Simply upload your `filename.js` file in the **assets** folder.

then drop the following in your `theme.liquid` **head** section:

```
{{ 'filename.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

by the way, you should **rename your file and add .liquid extension**

```
filename.js.liquid
```

Good luck!

Comment: what is the benefit of adding the `.liquid` extension?

Comment: @Ronnie the .liquid extension allows you to use liquid in your js and css files.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have tried everything, but I am including jQuery, then Slick, then a file using Slick, and it keeps saying "slick is not a function" despite loading all the files correctly.

Comment: I get an error  `Refused to apply style from ... because its MIME type ('text/x-liquid') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Answer (score 45):

If I understand correctly, the [asset_url filter](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/filters/asset-url) is what you are looking for.

To include a JS file in a .liquid file, you use:

```
{{ 'script.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

And a CSS file:

```
{{ 'style.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update on this @Steph-Sharp, I was trying to include these files in the "Page" and not the theme. I tried using the asset_url, but it does not work there...

Comment: @gagneet You can use the `asset_url` filter in any .liquid file, so it should work fine in page.liquid. Perhaps you could post some of your code if you're still having problems with it.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to pollute the global namespace you can restrict the JavaScript or CSS to certain areas.

Shopify uses a simple if statement together with the page-handle for that(for www.foo.com/abcd/bar - "bar" would be the handle).

```
{% if page.handle == "bar" %}
    {{ 'your_custom_javascript.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
    {{ 'your_custom_css.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% endif %}
```

This is extremely useful if you want to make smaller changes to certain pages.

Answer (score 1):

For JS files, never create the file directly via Shopifys "Create a blank file"-dialogue.
Instead, create the file locally as .js (not .js.liquid), then upload to the assets folder.

You can then simply reference the file in the theme.liquid head section:

```
{{ 'filename.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

Background:

It seems that Shopify always sets the mime type to text/x-liquid when creating new files and if liquid is used for the theme, regardless of the file extension.
This will then result in a browser error like this one from Chrome:

*Refused to apply style from ... because its MIME type
('text/x-liquid') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict
MIME checking is enabled*

Answer (score 0):

Open theme.liquid and check how the css and js are included and add yours by following them.Add your custom file to assets.[Css And Js Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5WFQ.png)
Image attached