# Shopify: Combine HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

I have following code

```
<div id="next-shipment"></div>
var date = new Date(); // today using client's timezone
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // move to tomorrow
date.setUTCHours(11,0,0,0); // set time using UTC(GMT) timezone
document.getElementById("next-shipment").textContent = date.toLocaleString();
```

I created: **next-shipment.js** file in Shopify under "Assets folder" and pasted the Javascript code there.

I can't seem to combine these two codes so when I place HTML line`<div id="next-shipment"></div>` on homepage, nothing shows up.

Comment: Did you link the js. File in the html file? I have no experience with shopify, but if the html page doesnt load the js file, the code doesnt get executed. Take a look at the <script> html tag

Comment: It tried this code, but it doesn't work. I am still learning, I might have made  an error.
 <script src="next-shipment.js"></script><div id="next-shipment"></div>

Comment: you could also try and just put a <script type = "text/javscript"> *your pasted code* </script> instead of the old one into the html file

Comment: Still doesn't work. Here is the link to a working script: http://jsfiddle.net/47oxf8Lf/

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467240/adding-custom-css-and-js-to-shopify

Comment: I just tried this, it work but only for certain pages. 
I need to incorporate html and javascript into one line of code. I am just not sure if it's possible and how.

Comment: place the script after next-shipment div

Answer (score 0):

First. To include assets in your shopify theme you'll need to use this:
`{{ 'next-shipment.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}` **in your theme.liquid file**. Place it in the head area or at the end of your `<body>` whatever your preference may be.

https://docs.shopify.com/api/uiintegrations/scripttag

If it's still not executing--

Try wrapping your code with the jQuery document.ready function like so:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date(); // today using client's timezone
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // move to tomorrow
    date.setUTCHours(11,0,0,0); // set time using UTC(GMT) timezone
    $('#next-shipment').html(date.toLocaleString());
});`

Shopify already uses jQuery, so you're going to want to utilize that tool since it's already there.