# Is there a way to save search filters between sessions per user account on Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

So (for example) if a user selects their gender and pant size while searching on Shopify store, could those selections be saved and be in place when they visit again?
I'm open to switching to a new Shopify search app that would support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

There a few approaches that you can achieve this.

## Using cookies

You can save their choices as cookies and refer to them once they search modifying the search URL before redirecting or appending hidden files in the form so that they submit them as well.

## Creating a custom app

You can create a custom app with only one purpose to save the information to the customer metafields or tags.

Once you have this information you will be able to use the same logic as the cookie one but instead of relying on a cookie you will have access to the metafields directly.

## App

I don't think that there is an App that meets these criteria, but you can look it up. Yet it may be possible to hack up the Apps in a such way that you may be able to pass this information.

Comment: I actually wanted to go with your first suggestion, and did my research prior to posting the question here - but all that I've found so far is that cookies can't be read/written through liquid scripting in the theme code. If that is incorrect, could you please point me to some documentation page that I can use as my starting point?

Comment: Yes you are correct, you can't read them from liquid. You need to use JS to read/write and add them as get arguments in your search url.

Comment: I see. And going by the method in this post, I'll be able to read them as liquid variables?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467240/adding-custom-css-and-js-to-shopify

Comment: No cookies are save in the front-end, liquids outputs information from the back-end. So the liquid code is executed way before the cookies are loaded. There is NO WAY to get cookies via Liquid code. Can't make this more clear. You can't get something when it's not there yet.